# Vnc connects but nothing is there

Tags: vnc

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and just installed a VNCserver on Gnome.

To do it, as it was the first time I tried it, I read an online guide.

The result is I have the VNC server installed and I can connect to it, but when I do it from my Android tablet it only appears a grey screen.

This is the content of my config file:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP     Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

And this are the errors of the Xtightvnc log:

```
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: can't open file '/home/ubuntu/.Xresources'
```

I achieved to fix the problems with the fonts, I only have to struggle with the xrdb, and I have no idea on how to fix it.

And just to clarify, when I installed the packets I install all of this, and maybe more:

```
$ sudo apt-get install \
  gnome-panel \
  gnome-settings-daemon \
  metacity nautilus \
  gnome-terminal \
  x11-xserver-utils
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code as code. Either use the backtick or click { } .

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if there is no monitor on a server. Make sure that your monitor is plugged in.

If not try these:

1. ssh/putty into monitorless server
2. enter "vnc4server :1"
3. enter "export DISPLAY=:1"
4. enter "x-session-manager &"
5. exit terminal session and you should now be able to vnc into the server with "vncviewer server_name :1"

p.s. taken from ubuntu forums. (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820693)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu omykoms.  I suggest you add a link to the Ubuntu forums page where you got the information from.

Comment: For sure: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820693

Comment: I edited the first post with more info and some improvements. What you purpose I can't do it because it seems the android version of putty it only works as a SSG client, and as my vncserver config is without SSH I can't connect to it.